# Confusion about airflow resistivity units

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, acoustics, dimensional-analysis

1. What is difference between $\frac{Pa·s}{m}$ and $\frac{Pa·s}{m^2}$? What does that "$2$" after "$m$" mean? I saw both versions,and I dont know if they are same thing or not,no idea what that $2$ is supposed to mean.
2. $\frac{Pa·s}{m}$ is 1 MKS Rayl,correct?
3. What is "1 newton-second per cubic meter ($\frac{N·s}{m^3}$)"???
   First I see $\frac{Pa·s}{m}$,then $\frac{Pa·s}{m^2}$ and now $\frac{N·s}{m^3}$ ...  this is madness!

If you could explain to me in easy to understand way what exactly do these units mean that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I don't know anything about airflow resistivity.  What follows is my guess based on the units you have mentioned, but perhaps it's not the intended usage.

Rewrite $\frac{Pa·s}{m}$ as $\frac{Pa}{m/s}$.  Now it's easier to think of it in terms of a pressure drop ($Pa$) per unit speed ($m/s$). The idea is you have some obstruction, and when air flows through, there's a pressure drop from the upstream side to the downstream side due to the dissipation in the obstruction. If the pressure drop is proportional to the speed of the air, you can conveniently characterize the resistance to flow by dividing the pressure drop by the speed.  I imagine this is the case for low flow rates.  I would expect the pressure drop to go more like the speed squared for high flow rates.

That is for a single obstruction, treated as one entity.  But if you have air flow through some duct, the longer the duct, the more resistance.  In this case, you might want to know the resistance *per unit length*.  This is what I imagine is meant by the unit $\frac{Pa·s}{m^2}$: it is the pressure drop along the direction of flow, per unit speed, per unit length.

As for your question 3, as pointed out by MatMorPau22, it's just a different way of writing the same unit.

Answer (score 0):

The $2$ after meters means meters squared. A side of a square is 2 meters (2m), and it's area is 4 meters squared ($4m^2$).

$\frac{Pa·s}{m}=\frac{N·s}{m^3}$, since $[P]=Pa=\big[\frac{N}{m^2}\big]$

Comment: But why its squared? Can you please be more verbose and stop using equations? I would like thorough and detailed explanation of  these units,when I look at certain type of porous material,and it have certain value of any of the three mentioned units,in my current state of knowledge I would be completly unable to productively use this material information becose I dont understand it

Comment: @wavscientist If you want to understand material properties, ask a question about the properties and not the units.

Comment: If I want to understand material properties,I must first learn the units that describe them.

Comment: But what properties must have this units? Can you write down the equation where it comes from?

Comment: For example,imagine a airduct pipe with square shape,the diameter is 1cm.Its filled with air and there is blower at one end,there will be certain volume of air flowing,now what if we put 1cm cube of porous material with 15000 Pa.s/m resistivity into the pipe? How much air will flow through the duct after we obstruct it with thus porous cube?